# Add a static option to a selection in a batch "vue-search-select"

Tags: vuejs2

I am using package "vue-search-select"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-search-select

I want to add a static option on selection that won't be filtered

I didn’t find any properties in the library for such a condition, so I tried to do it through the filterPredicate

but the documentation says that it accepts a regular string, the program requires the function

maybe someone faced such a problem? how can you decide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (text, inputText) => {
      if(text === ('static_text')) {
            return text;
      }
      return text.match(escapedRegExp(inputText));
}
```

I didn’t find the built-in functionality in the library in new versions, I had to fantasize a little with the existing properties, one of the working options is to disable filtering by specific text